# Execute and be able to edit each line in a function in real time, without debug?

Tags: r

suppose I have this function

```
function_to_run <- function(data){ 
     a = 2+data 
     b = 4+9 
     c = 0 
     a = a + b + c 
     return(a)
}
```

what I want to do is execute each line in the function one at a time and be able to change the values, for example say I execute the second line `b=4+9` but while in the function I want to change that in real time to `b=5+9` instead, is there a way to do this.

If I use debug it will just allow me to execute but I can't run it.
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? I guess you could use `b=readline('b= ')` and then the function would prompt the user in the console to enter the value of `b`, but I'm not sure what the goal is here

Comment: I'm not sure what is your aim, but tibble::lst() allows you to build components sequentially.

Comment: @divibisan sorry was not clear; but I have a really complicated function that requires multiple inputs, however there are no errors in it, I just want to be able to step through each line and modify them when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run statements within debug:  f() would have given 18 but it gave 19 because we run the highlighted statement.

```
> f <- function_to_run <- function() { 
+      a = 2+3 
+      b = 4+9 
+      c = 0 
+      a = a + b + c 
+      return(a)
+ }
> debug(f)
> f()
debugging in: f()
debug at #1: {
    a = 2 + 3
    b = 4 + 9
    c = 0
    a = a + b + c
    return(a)
}
Browse[2]> 
debug at #2: a = 2 + 3
Browse[2]> 
debug at #3: b = 4 + 9
Browse[2]> 
debug at #4: c = 0
Browse[2]> b <- 5+9  # <-------------------- change b
Browse[2]> 
debug at #5: a = a + b + c
Browse[2]> 
debug at #6: return(a)
Browse[2]> 
exiting from: f()
[1] 19
```

Comment: this looks promising, would I still be able to pass it a variable, what if the function accepts a as an object?

Comment: The code you run can use available variables including function arguments.  The example in the question passed data but did not use it so I removed it in the code in the answer.